# Horizontally center images with different sizes in a jQuery Mobile listview

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm developing a very simple app which loads a json object into a jquery mobile listview.

The json object has:

- an image
- a title
- an url

The problem is that the images do not have a fixed width nor a fixed ratio. So I can get some images that are taller than the others.
I would like all the images centered on the left side of the screen, but I don't know how do it.

Attached a screenshot with a red line that shows the "center" of the images. As you can see, the third picture, is smaller and not centered like the other images.

[image: not centered image]

How can I center the images in this imaginary column in a JQuery Mobile listview?

Thank you for your help,
    Rik.

Comment: Can you share how you've structured your list in a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is a **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/nwNc6/)**

I restructured the list to put the thumbs inside a DIV. The LI is given the jQM class of ui-li-has-thumb and the new DIV gets ui-li-thumb. These are the ones normally applied automatically when an image is found.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a">
  <li class="ui-li-has-thumb"><a href="#">
    <div class="ui-li-thumb">
    <img src="http://..." class="imgThumb"  />
    </div>
    <h2>Broken Bells</h2>
    <p>Broken Bells</p></a>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Then I add CSS classes to make the container 80px wide with its contents centered horizontally, and to give the image max width and height of 80px:

```
div .ui-li-thumb {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
.imgThumb {
  max-width: 80px;
  max-height: 80px;  
}
```

Comment: Mmmhh... Ok, I have horizontally centered the image with success... but now I lost the vertical centering! ><
I need the images in the center of the `<div class="ui-li-thumb">`. I have believed to do it by copying the old code in the correct position, but the css attibute `position:absolute` moves the things around in the screen. :(

Comment: I solved the problem by using your html and the following css:
`div .ui-li-thumb{

    width: 80px;
    height:80px;

    border: 1px solid black;
}

.imgThumb {

    position:absolute;

    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;

    max-width:70px;
    max-height:70px;

}`

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/listviews/):

"To add thumbnails to the left of a list item, simply add an image inside a list item as the first child element. **The framework will scale the image to *80 pixels square***."